# how to implement fast query response in android?

Tags: java, mysql, rest, web-applications

I have a huge database with multiple column(11) and rows(+4000).

data around +44000.

I want to design an Android application which will display relevant rows of products from DB.

columns are
id(index) , name , price , model_No, time_creation , stock available ...

eg

```
{"id":1,"name":"product1","price":100,"model":1,time:"20-oct-15" , stock:200,}
```

In application query can be be `name=product1` or `time>20-oct-14` or `price<500` or `stock>1` or combination of more than 1 query.

and response will be all possible `id` .

Currently i am facing a problem of speed response. In a asynctask ,
the new thread generated takes more time in loading all relevant results & then displaying.

ie.
it loads a1 & b1 then display which is time consuming task.

Plz suggest tools or techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on `val` column. without index, the application has to go through all the rows to find the relevant rows.